Azure functions app deploy - Request timeout error while using AzureFunctionApp@2
I am encountering an issue while deploying Python packages to a function app deployed within ASE V3 and connected to a storage account through a Private Endpoint. Have any of you encountered a similar issue before?
Your assistance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.
I have verified the envt variables and its looking exactly the way it should be for webjobsstorage and route_all etc. DNS is also resolving but its giving response after 2 request timeout and Always on setting is ON, Function app is on running state verified from KUDU URL as well. I am not sure if 2 DNS request timeout is causing the issue. Can you please suggest some options which can be further tested.

##[error]Error: Failed to fetch App Service 'func_name' details. Error: Request timeout: /subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.Web/sites//?api-version=2016-08-01

- task: AzureFunctionApp@2
  displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
  inputs:
    connectedServiceNameARM: '<Service Connection Name>'
    appType: 'functionAppLinux'
    appName: 'func_name'
    deployToSlotOrASE: true
    resourceGroupName: 'RG_name'
    slotName: 'production'
    package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    appSettings: -RequestTimeout 5000

I have verified the envt variables and its looking exactly the way it should be for AzureWebJobsStorage and WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL, WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER etc. DNS is also resolving but its giving response after 2 request timeout and Always on setting is ON, Function app is on running state verified from KUDU URL as well. I am not sure if 2 DNS request timeout is causing the issue. Can you please suggest some options which can be further tested.
Blank Error Image - enter image description here
How it should be - enter image description here
Local deployment from VM deployed under DevOps Subnet - enter image description here
FUNCTION_APP.py file
import azure.functions as func 
from azure.storage.blob.aio import BlobServiceClient
import logging
import os
import io
import time
import psutil
import aiohttp
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.middleware.gzip import GZipMiddleware
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse

from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor
from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry.sdk.resources import Resource, ResourceAttributes

configure_azure_monitor()

VERSION = "1.0.7"

logging.getLogger('azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy').setLevel(logging.WARNING)

fast_app = FastAPI() 
fast_app.add_middleware(GZipMiddleware, minimum_size=6000)

app = func.FunctionApp()

stopwatch = None

images_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(os.environ['sa_images_connection'], max_chunk_get_size=64*1024)
web_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(os.environ['sa_staticweb_connection'])

    
def stopwatch_lap(initial_time: float, message: str|None = None) -> float:
    elapsed_time = time.perf_counter() - initial_time
    if message is not None:
        logging.info(f"{message} Elapsed time: {elapsed_time:.4f} s")
    
    return time.perf_counter()

host.json file
    {
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
        "routePrefix": ""
    }
  }
}


What agent are you using to run the deploy job? If Microsoft-hosted agents, you might need to add the IP ranges or Service tags of the agents run in the same Azure geography as your organization into the whitelist of the Private Endpoint. See the following docs: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#networking) and (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/service-tags-overview#available-service-tags)

If you are using the self-hosted agents installed on yourself local machines or VMs, you first need to try to manually run the deployment from the machine to see if it can work. If it also does not work, you also need to check if the IP address of the machine has been added to the whitelist of the Private Endpoint.

Yes, I am trying to connect it from a self hosted agent.

As suggested above, you first need to try to manually run the deployment from the self-hosted agent machine to ensure it can work. @Lbits

Hi @BrightRan-MSFT, Thanks for the response, my pipeline is working now when I am trying to deploy package but the error still persists under Functions tab "We were not able to load some functions in the list due to errors. Refresh the page to try again." - "Encountered an error (ServiceUnavailable) from host runtime." due to which functions are still not showing up here post deployment.

We have done DNS config as per this - create an Azure DNS private zone named .appserviceenvironment.net
create an A record in that zone that points * to the ILB IP address
create an A record in that zone that points @ to the ILB IP address
create an A record in that zone that points *.scm to the ILB IP address

I can get the DNS check and nslookup response from a VM deployed under DevOps Subnet for KUDU URL (scm) and function app URL (fncappname.asename.appserviceenvironment.net)

So now, you can successfully deploy the function app to Azure, but when you try to run the function from Azure, it gets failed. Right? @Lbits

No, even though the deployment from DevOps is successful. Under Overview page > I see nothing under Functions Tab. Generally, post deployment a new functions gets listed under functions tab but not in current case of function app deployed under ASE V3. It still comes as blank for some reason.

@Lbits if possible can you share your function repo?

@Lbits, What do you mean "Under Overview page > I see nothing under Functions Tab."? Where is the "Overview page"? On Azure DevOps or Azure Portal? Can you provide the screenshots of this? If you deploy from local, does the issue exist?

@BrightRan-MSFT he means to say Azure Function app overview page. whenever a functions are deployed in Function app, they are visible in Overview under functions section Image.

@BrightRan-MSFT, please find the image above attached.

@Lbits This error occurs when function is not able to read host.json file. either some syntax error is there in file or file is not available in required directory

@Lbits can you share your host.josn file?

@Lbits, Check if the issue exists when you manually deploy from local? And check if the  function.json file is existing?

@Lbits I tried to deploy function app in Dedicated app service plan, I am also getting same error. but same repo is working fine in Consumption plan.  Can you try to deploy you function to a consumption or Function premium plan and see if it works
app service plan error-image, consumption plan image

@Lbits, How did you create the Python function app project? Did you create it via Visual Studio or other ways? When create the project via Visual Studio, it generally will automatically generate the function.json, host.json and other config files by default. If you create the project via other ways, you can try to create it via Visual Studio with the same code of the function app, then check if the issue can be fixed.

Hi team, the issue still persist. I created another function app under the same App Serice Envt with 2 Pvt endpoint blob and file connected to storage account with exact same params and envt. variables but the issue still persists and nothing gets listed underneath and keep getting runtime version : error.

I cant redeploy function to a consumption or Function premium plan seems like its not available under ASE. Is that right understanding ?
